# Wrong iCloud email

Tags: icloud, email

How do I change my iCloud account email? I use a different email for iCloud than iTunes for several reasons and I accidentally put in the wrong email for my iCloud and it's not allowing me to change the email, only the password. I don't want to delete anything else on my phone, I just want to change the email.

Answer (score 1):

If you log out of the iCloud account (using the big Delete Account button at the bottom of Settings > iCloud), it will only delete the things that came from that iCloud account. Things like contacts, mail, calendars, reminders, etc.

It won't delete music, apps, or iMessages. Those are each managed separately in their respective settings screens.